# Textured plane doesn't match original image

Tags: rendering, image

Image is 4K.

*Render settings:*

- Blender Render
- Ortho camera with perfectly matched plane
- Shadeless material
- All kinds of interpolation in texture settings are disabled
- Filter size is lowest possible

**There is difference, even in full resolution:**

[image]

Without *Gamma* node it is barely visible, but I am not sure which resolution will be final 4K or 1080P, so I put 50% of 4K in render settings.
And at half-sized render original image is obviously sharper.

Full oversampling also doesn't do anything with that.

Comment: Are you looking to file a bug report?

Comment: I just don't know whether it's a bug or impossible thing